# How to plot 3 lines based on filters with macro in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a lot of records in the following formatting.
I would like to plot 3 lines (min, avg, max) with the epoch date values on x-axis and values on y-axis. I tried filtering on "min" and plotting it, but the data doesn't stay in the graph when I switch to the next "avg" filter. Any idea how I can create 1 graph with 3 lines for min, avg and max values?

```
date            type value
1476255600000   min  226.1
1476255600000   avg  227
1476255600000   max  228
1476342000000   min  225.9
1476342000000   avg  227
1476342000000   max  227.9
1476342000000   max  228
1476342000000   min  226.1
1476342000000   avg  226.9
1476428400000   min  225.7
1476428400000   max  227.7
1476428400000   avg  226.7
1476514800000   avg  226.8
1476514800000   min  225.7
1476514800000   max  227.8
1476514800000   max  227.7
1476514800000   avg  226.7
1476514800000   min  225.8
1476601200000   min  225.8
1476601200000   avg  226.8
1476601200000   min  225.7
1476601200000   max  227.7
1476601200000   max  227.8
1476687600000   min  225.5
1476687600000   max  227.5
```

Comment: Check this - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355462/create-line-chart-for-many-series)

Comment: @jivko When I follow this tutorial I get this as output: http://i.imgur.com/8PKuEUP.png. I need to get rid of "sum of value". Any idea how to do this?

Comment: When you click on the chart, on the right will appear the pivot chart fields. There in the lower right corner you'll find VALUES with Sum of values inside. Click on it and select Value Field Settings. There you can select what to display instead of SUM.

Comment: @jivko Thank you, this solved my problem! Strange that I couldn't find this answer on stack. Please create an answer so that I can assign your answer as helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18355462/create-line-chart-for-many-series)

When you click on the chart, on the right will appear the pivot chart fields. There in the lower right corner you'll find VALUES with Sum of values inside. Click on it and select Value Field Settings. There you can select what to display instead of SUM.